# how to remove salesforce hover highlight on pageblock table.

Tags: visualforce, pageblocktable

I am changing the pageblocktable cell colors dynamically based on value but due to salesforce standard style on pageblocktable removing my color.

please suggest.

[image: it is changing on mousover]

[image]

Comment: You should really include your markup.

Comment: @andran sorry i didn't get you

Comment: @lokeshkumar post your vf page code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This really depends on your Visualforce code and what you're checking against. For each column you can use a formula to determine whether or not a class gets used. For example:

```
<style>
  .green {
    background: green;
  }
</style>

<apex:pageBlock>
  <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!myTable}" var="t">
    <apex:column styleClass={!IF(t.DateField__c > TODAY()), 'green', '')}     value="{!t.DateField__c}" />
  </apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

You've not specified much, but the trick is here:

```
{!IF(t.DateField__c > TODAY), 'green', '')}
```

In other words for this example, if `DateField__c` is greater than today, return `green`. `green` is a CSS class and the formula is within the `styleClass` parameter. So, if the date is indeed greater than today, it'll render something like this:

```
<apex:column styleClass="green" [...]
```

**Edit**

To answer your second question, in your CSS you'd need something like this:

```
.green:hover {
    colour: darkgreen;
}
```

Salesforce will have some standard styling and `:hover` will be one of them. You'll want to override/cascade over that by using your own class.

Alternatively, you could do:

```
.green {
  background: green !important;
}
```

Although I'd avoid using this personally.

Comment: this thing i am getting but when i hover on the row it is disappearing bcoz salesforce pagetable standard class highlight - how do i remove that standard hover

Comment: @lokeshkumar See my edit.

Comment: sorry to say but it's not working

Comment: Strange because I have exactly that in the `styleClass` in one of the first VF Applications I ever made, although I had admittedly used `!important`.

Answer (score 0):

The background hover is a feature of pageBlockTable. If you want to remove it *entirely*, use [dataTable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_dataTable.htm) instead. You'll also lose the formatting, including borders, colors, etc that salesforce uses by default.

If you just want to keep the green color, wrap your text in an inner element:

```
<apex:column headerValue="Column Name">
    <span style="display: inline-block; width: 100%; background-color: {!row.bgcolor}">
        {!row.dateValue}
    </span>
</apex:column>
```

Feel free to adjust as you need to.